# How to use ATMega USART in synchronous mode using XCK pin

Tags: avr, c, codevision

I'm working on a project with ATMega64 and I have a problem with one of the USART interfaces which is going to work in synchronous mode.

when trying to send a test data like:

```
char data[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

everything goes fine, but trying with:

```
char data[10] = {'1', '2', '3', 'A', 'B', '6', 'C', '8', '9'};
```

causes a problem with `non-number` characters. it looks like my problem is in MSB bits that they can't be  transmitted properly.

As this error occurs on every `letter` character that seems to be something that I've forgotten to set / check. since I haven't worked with this type of micro-controller for a while, maybe I've missed some configurations.

every sending and receiving data works fine in asynchronous mode but setting `UMSEL` to enable synchronous mode and using XCK pin effects the transaction.

here is my synchronous configurations:

Master micro (XCK output):

```
PORTD = 0b00000100;
DDRD  = 0b00101000;

// USART1 initialization
// Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
// USART1 Receiver: On
// USART1 Transmitter: On
// USART1 Mode: Sync. Master UCPOL=1
// USART1 Baud Rate: 2400
UCSR1A=(0<<RXC1) | (0<<TXC1) | (0<<UDRE1) | (0<<FE1) | (0<<DOR1) | (0<<UPE1) | (0<<U2X1) | (0<<MPCM1);
UCSR1B=(1<<RXCIE1) | (0<<TXCIE1) | (0<<UDRIE1) | (1<<RXEN1) | (1<<TXEN1) | (0<<UCSZ12) | (0<<RXB81) | (0<<TXB81);
UCSR1C=(1<<UMSEL1) | (0<<UPM11) | (0<<UPM10) | (0<<USBS1) | (1<<UCSZ11) | (1<<UCSZ10) | (1<<UCPOL1);
UBRR1H=0x08;
UBRR1L=0xFF;
```

Slave micro (XCK input):

```
PORTD = 0b00100100;
DDRD  = 0b00001000;

// USART1 initialization
// Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
// USART1 Receiver: On
// USART1 Transmitter: On
// USART1 Mode: Sync. Slave UCPOL=1
UCSR1A=(0<<RXC1) | (0<<TXC1) | (0<<UDRE1) | (0<<FE1) | (0<<DOR1) | (0<<UPE1) | (0<<U2X1) | (0<<MPCM1);
UCSR1B=(1<<RXCIE1) | (0<<TXCIE1) | (0<<UDRIE1) | (1<<RXEN1) | (1<<TXEN1) | (0<<UCSZ12) | (0<<RXB81) | (0<<TXB81);
UCSR1C=(1<<UMSEL1) | (0<<UPM11) | (0<<UPM10) | (0<<USBS1) | (1<<UCSZ11) | (1<<UCSZ10) | (1<<UCPOL1);
```

the problem comes again exactly on every iteration so I don't think this data loss would comes from a connection problem.

or maybe in synchronous mode I should always send a spare bit and using 9 bits for a 8 bits data. does this have a meaning?

I'm using CodeVisionAVR as the compiler but also every other code in C language would be helpful.

Comment: So you can send letters in asynchonous mode? What do you get on the receiving end? Don't you have to set the BAUD rate too on the slave end?

Comment: Yes, in asynchronous mode everything is fine, but in synchronous mode I'm getting `123?56789` instead of `123A56789`. also checking input data in `hex` view not `ascii`, shows that I'm receiving some extra `0x3F` data.

Comment: None of those set the MSB.  Are you perhaps running a value to printable hex conversion somewhere which is buggy and fails to account for the skip in ASCII codes between `'9'` and `'A'` ?  A `'?'` looks like a software decoder saying it is confused.   You might consider using a cheap USB-based logic analyzer to see what is actually getting clocked onto the wire.

Comment: this is what I get in `hex` mode without converting: `31-32-33-01-35-36-37-38-39-31-32-33-01-35-36-37-38-39`. and this is repeated on every iteration.  I'm just receiving `0x01` instead of `0x41` (ascii number for `A`). I'm loosing two MSB bits.